# Closure on the result of a `useState` hook causes annoying behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I have a component like this:

```
const MyInput = ({ defaultValue, id, onChange }) => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setValue(value);

    onChange(id, value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Where I want to it to behave like an uncontrolled component, but I want it to have an initial value that we can set.

In my parent component this works fine,

```
export default function App() {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (id, value) => {
    console.log(id, value, JSON.stringify(formState)); // For debugging later
    setFormState({ ...formState, [id]: value });
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(formState, null, 2)}</pre>
      <MyInput id="1" defaultValue="one" onChange={handleChange} />
      <MyInput id="2" defaultValue="two" onChange={handleChange} />
      <MyInput id="3" defaultValue="three" onChange={handleChange} />
      <MyInput id="4" defaultValue="four" onChange={handleChange} />
      <MyInput id="5" defaultValue="five" onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

but the problem is that the value of `formState` doesn't reflect the values on the `MyInputs` until they fire an onchange event.

So ok, I can just add a 'component did mount' useEffect hook on the MyInput to fire an onChange when the component first mounts.

```
const MyInput = ({ defaultValue, id, onChange }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(id, defaultValue);
  }, []);

  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setValue(value);

    onChange(id, value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-greider-fx52q?file=/src/App.js:69-459)

But this doesn't behave how we want. Each of the MyInputs do call onChange when they first mount, but reference to `formState` is stale for the main onChange handler in each case.

ie. the console.log output when the page first loads is:

```
1 one {}
2 two {}
3 three {}
4 four {}
5 five {}
```

So I've thought that using a ref could solve this. eg:

```
export default function App() {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({});

  const formStateRef = useRef(formState);

  useEffect(() => {
    formStateRef.current = formState;
  }, [formState]);

  const handleChange = (id, value) => {
    console.log(
      id,
      value,
      JSON.stringify(formState),
      JSON.stringify(formStateRef)
    );
    setFormState({ ...formStateRef.current, [id]: value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(formState, null, 2)}</pre>
      <MyInput id="1" defaultValue="one" onChange={handleChange} />
      <MyInput id="2" defaultValue="two" onChange={handleChange} />
      <MyInput id="3" defaultValue="three" onChange={handleChange} />
      <MyInput id="4" defaultValue="four" onChange={handleChange} />
      <MyInput id="5" defaultValue="five" onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-elgamal-s4d1y?file=/src/App.js:468-1346)

This doesn't work. It appears that all of the change handlers fire *before* useEffect on formState has the chance to update the ref.

```
1 one {} {"current":{}}
2 two {} {"current":{}}
3 three {} {"current":{}}
4 four {} {"current":{}}
5 five {} {"current":{}}
```

I guess I could directly mutate the ref in the handleChange function, and set that?

```
export default function App() {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({});

  const formStateRef = useRef(formState);

  const handleChange = (id, value) => {
    console.log(
      id,
      value,
      JSON.stringify(formState),
      JSON.stringify(formStateRef)
    );

    formStateRef.current = { ...formStateRef.current, [id]: value };
    setFormState(formStateRef.current);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(formState, null, 2)}</pre>
      <MyInput id="1" defaultValue="one" onChange={handleChange} />
      <MyInput id="2" defaultValue="two" onChange={handleChange} />
      <MyInput id="3" defaultValue="three" onChange={handleChange} />
      <MyInput id="4" defaultValue="four" onChange={handleChange} />
      <MyInput id="5" defaultValue="five" onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-lewin-0xz08?file=/src/App.js:472-1322)

This does work. But this use of refs makes me a bit uneasy.

What's the standard way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Why not pass `defaultValue` and `onChange` props directly to the underlying inputs and allow the state updates in the parent to occur normally? That is how an uncontrolled input would work anyway. Seems you are overly complicating things.

Comment: @DrewReese - you mean that's how controlled  inputs would work? - My actual use case is more complicated than this, it involves dynamic rendering of form elements from a JSON definition. For my usecase, it's just easier to keep them as uncontrolled components.

Comment: No, controlled inputs use the `value` attribute and are controlled by state, uncontrolled inputs take the `defaultValue` attribute for the initial value and don't have any state driving/controlling them.

Comment: Anyway, if you take your first example and use a functional state update you'll get the output I think you expect: `setFormState(formState => ({ ...formState, [id]: value }));`. You are trying to populate your form state when the inputs mount, right?

Comment: @DrewReese Oh huh - I did not realise that you could pass a `defaultValue` prop to basic elements. In anycase - I still have the same problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-zhukovsky-6sdqu

Comment: @DrewReese Yes - I am trying populate the form state when the inputs mount. The top level component doesn't know how to populate the state itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take your first example and simply use a functional state update instead I think you'll achieve what you are after.

## Issue

With the the non-functional update, all the inputs mount at the same time and all invoke their `onChange` handlers. The `handleChange` callback uses the state from the render cycle it was enclosed in. When all inputs enqueue updates in the same render cycle, each subsequent update overwrites the previous state update. The last input to update state is the one that "wins". This is why you see:

```
{
  "5": "five"
}
```

Instead of

```
{
  "1": "one",
  "2": "two",
  "3": "three",
  "4": "four",
  "5": "five"
}
```

## Solution

Use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state, not the state from the previous render cycle.

```
setFormState(formState => ({ ...formState, [id]: value }));
```

From here suggestions are only optimizations

1. Curry the input id in the handler, makes for one less props to pass and process. The children inputs also don't need to know it to handle changes.

   ```
   const handleChange = (id) => (value) => {
     setFormState((formState) => ({ ...formState, [id]: value }));
   };
   ```
2. Pass `defaultValue` to the `defaultValue` prop of the underlying inputs.

   ```
   const MyInput = ({ defaultValue, onChange }) => {
     useEffect(() => {
       onChange(defaultValue);
     }, []);

     const handleChange = (e) => {
       const { value } = e.target;
       onChange(value);
     };

     return (
       <div>
         <input type="text" defaultValue={defaultValue} onChange={handleChange} />
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```
3. Pass the `id` in the curried handler

   ```
   <MyInput defaultValue="one" onChange={handleChange(1)} />
   <MyInput defaultValue="two" onChange={handleChange(2)} />
   <MyInput defaultValue="three" onChange={handleChange(3)} />
   <MyInput defaultValue="four" onChange={handleChange(4)} />
   <MyInput defaultValue="five" onChange={handleChange(5)} />
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit closure-on-the-result-of-a-usestate-hook-causes-annoying-behaviour]

demo code

```
const MyInput = ({ defaultValue, onChange }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(defaultValue);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    onChange(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" defaultValue={defaultValue} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (id) => (value) => {
    setFormState((formState) => ({ ...formState, [id]: value }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(formState, null, 2)}</pre>
      <MyInput defaultValue="one" onChange={handleChange(1)} />
      <MyInput defaultValue="two" onChange={handleChange(2)} />
      <MyInput defaultValue="three" onChange={handleChange(3)} />
      <MyInput defaultValue="four" onChange={handleChange(4)} />
      <MyInput defaultValue="five" onChange={handleChange(5)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Huh, did not realise you could set state from previous state. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @dwjohnston Welcome. The official React docs are an amazing resource! :D Cheers and good luck!