# When does passing a callback to useState setter actually make a difference?

Tags: reactjs

While learning React, I've been advised countless times to prefer passing a callback to my state setter, than to just use  the state variable inside it:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

const incrementCount = () => {
  // do not do this
  setCount(count + 1);

  // do this instead
  setCount(oldCount => oldCount + 1);
}
```

Now, I understand the asynchronous nature of state setters from useState, and that they might get put on hold for batch execution under some circumstances

But I am failing to think of a valid scenario in which the first example could actually be at fault.

Can someone please educate me on this?

Comment: You probably want to read: [React Docs - useState#Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66040590/closure-on-the-result-of-a-usestate-hook-causes-annoying-behaviour

Comment: This is a great article: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-state-lazy-initialization-and-function-updates

Comment: See this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-solomon-7tm62?file=/src/App.js:345-349) which demonstrates the difference.

Comment: Thanks guys :) So this becomes an issue only with asynchronous logic inside the state dispatch function?